# Alterar componentes do Fragment através de uma Activity

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Estou fazendo uma aplicação com `NavigationDrawer`, e para não criar sempre outra `activity`, estou usando `fragments`, onde a cada clique faço o `replace` no `FrameLayout` que deixei setado como principal. Como eu acesso os componentes que cada `fragment` possui? Ex: `TextView` (alterar o text dele);

---

Minha classe Fragment

```
public class EscolheEspecialidadeFragment extends Fragment{

    private TextView tvTeste;
    private View rootView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_escolhe_especialidade, container, false);
        tvTeste = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTeste);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void setTextoText(String texto)
    {
        tvTeste.setText(texto);
    }
}
```

Método responsável por chamar o fragment

```
public void clickHojeAmanha(View view)
    {
        EscolheEspecialidadeFragment fragment = new EscolheEspecialidadeFragment();

        FragmentManager fn = getFragmentManager();
        fn.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        fragment.setTextoText("teste");
    }
```

Toda vez que a aplicação tenta setar o texto, ela dá crash e encerra. Por favor, onde está o meu erro?

Comment: Você quer que código na *Activity* altere o texto de um *TextView* existente no *layout* do *fragment*?

Comment: Sim, seria possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada *fragment* deve ser responsável por gerir/manipular o conteúdo das suas *views*.

Se a necessidade dessa alteração surge fora dele, disponibilize métodos públicos que possam ser chamados do exterior.

Por exemplo para alterar o texto de um Textview:

```
public void setTextViewText(String text){

    textView.setText(text);
}
```

A *activity* tem uma referência ao *Fragment*, quando quiser alterar o texto desse *TextView* usa o método assim:

```
fragmentObject.setTextViewText("qualquer coisa");
```

Comment: o findviewbyid do textview, eu faço na classe do fragment, no onCreateView ou na minha Activity principal?

Comment: Como o *TextView* está no *layout* do *Fragment*, o `findViewById()` tem de ser feito no *Fragment*

Comment: Amigo, por favor. Olhe minha outra resposta com a minha classe

Comment: O problema é que a transacção não é aplicada de imediato após a chamada a *commit*, assim,  quando o método `setTextViewText()` é chamado, o `onCreateView()` ainda não foi executado. Entre a linha onde está o *commit* e a chamada ao método inclua esta: `fn.executePendingTransactions();`

Comment: Exatamente, deu certo! Obrigado