# Como inserir marcadores (marker) em um mapa em outro fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou desenvolvendo um *app* Android onde você insere uma lista de tarefas de courier (pegar algo em ponto `A` e levar ao ponto `B`) e estes pontos são mostrados em um mapa.

O *App* tem dois fragmentos:

1. `ReclyclerView` contendo a lista de tarefas.
2. mapa com marcadores mostrando pontos `A` e `B` de cada item da lista no `recyclerView`.

Quando o mapa é criado (ou recriado) ele pega as coordenadas do banco de dados (que também alimenta a lista de tarefas).

A questão surge ao inserir nova tarefa. Os novos marcadores só aparecem se forçar a recriação do mapa (girando o aparelho ou reiniciando o *app*).

Como eu faço pra inserir os marcadores no mapa ao inserir uma nova tarefa?

ATUALIZAÇÃO: Como observou Ack Lay minha pergunta carecia mais detalhes. E como uma imagem vale mais que mil palavras...

** Sou novo aqui e só posso publicar duas imagens...
Então serão as duas ultimas.

1.Ao abrir o aplicativo aparece um painel vazio na metade esquerda e um mapa vazio à direita.

2. Ao tocar no botão suspenso +, abre um form. para entrada da tarefa.
   Deve ser informado: O que vai ser transportado, onde pegar com quem ,onde entregar, para quem.
3. Formulário completo, toque em concluir e...
   [image: Card com informações da tarefa]
4. Os dados da tarefa são gravados no banco de dados. O ´adapter´ é atualizado junto com a ´recyclerview´ e o card aparece mostrando as informações. O mapa ainda está vazio.

** As operações no banco de dados (SQLite) são feitas por uma classe ´dbHelper´ com os métodos CRUD.

[image: Mapa com marcadores]

5. É preciso mudar a orientação do aparelho ou reiniciar o aplicativo para os marcadores aparecerem.

Ou seja, os marcadores aparecem quando o ´fragment´ é (re)criado. O que não funciona é a atualização do mapa, junto com o ´recyclerview´, quando insiro uma nova tarefa.

Agora cabe descrever a estrutura do *app*.

A atividade principal é

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

Ela carrega o layout que tem é formado por

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/myContainer"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/runFragment"
        android:name="br.com.medamais.motonoix.RecyclerFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_recycler" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/markersMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map"
        android:name="br.com.medamais.motonoix.MarkersFragment"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

A classe da lista de tarefas

```
public class RecyclerFragment extends Fragment
```

A classe do mapa

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment
```

O código é bem parecido com o que vc mandou, só está mais adaptado ao *app*.
Por exemplo, os *pins* são fixos. Não queremos que eles mudem ao tocar no mapa. Somente atualizando o card. Para evitar problemas de percurso.

Parece que tem diversas abordagens possíveis. Tenho alguma experiencia como desenvolvedor, mas este é meu primeiro app Android.

Imagino que a solução seja uma forma de acessar a instancia do mapa e adicionar o novo ´marker´.

Isso seria feito em ´A´ evento ´onClick()´ do ´positiveButton´ do dialogo que infla o formulário (ou seja, quando toque em CONFIRMAR). Ou ´B´ método ´dbHelper.insert()´

Mas deve haver outras formas.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

ATUALIZAÇÃO: Em resposta as dicas de @ramaral

Implementar a ´interface´ funcionou. Não foi nem preciso criar um ´listener´ customizado, uma vez que o botão  já havia implementado.

Mas ainda não terminou :-(

Quando o dispositivo está orientado na vertical (retrato), funciona corretamente. Porém, quando está na horizontal (paisagem) ainda não.

O layout na vertical é composto assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Na horizontal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/myContainer"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/runFragment"
        android:name="br.com.medamais.motonoix.RecyclerFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_recycler" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/markersMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map"
        android:name="br.com.medamais.motonoix.MarkersFragment"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout do fragmento do mapa

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/markersMapFragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    map:cameraTargetLat="-23.7941"
    map:cameraTargetLng="-46.8825"
    map:cameraZoom="13"
/>
```

A seguir, as partes de codigo que considero pertinentes a esta questão,
especialmente esta linha da ´MainActivity´:

```
MarkersFragment mFragment = (MarkersFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.viewpager);
```

Tentei  ´findFragmentById´ com R.id.markersMapFragment, R.id.myContainer, mas todas retornam null. A unica que retorna o objeto é R.id.viewpager e é a que funciona.

O fragment que mostra a lista e o botão +

```
public class RecyclerFragment extends Fragment implements AlertDialog.OnClickListener {
    ...
    ...
    public RecyclerFragment() { 
        this.mCallback = null;
    }
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ...        
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) mInflate.findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // abre o dialogo de inserção de dados
                dialogInsertRun();
            }
        });
        ...
        ...
    }

    public void dialogInsertRun() { // implementa a janela de dialogo de inserção de dados
        ...
        ...
        addRunDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // implementa botão <CONFIRMAR>

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { // Listener 'padrão'
                ...
                ...
                mCallback.addMarkersToMap(runData); // metodo definido na Activity
            }
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) { 
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ");
    }
    ...
    ...
    private OnOkButtonListener mCallback;
    public interface OnOkButtonListener {
        void addMarkersToMap(RunData runData);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Na ´activity´ que controla os fragmentos temos

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements RecyclerFragment.OnOkButtonListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // replace the splash theme with app theme
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        // finish is overdue
        checkDateLimit();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ScreenUtility utility = new ScreenUtility(this);
        if (utility.getWidth() < 500.0) {
            // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));

            // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    }

    ...
    ...
    public void addMarkersToMap(RunData runData) {
        if (runData != null) {
            MarkersFragment mFragment = (MarkersFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.viewpager);

            mFragment.addSingleMarker(runData); 
    }
}
```

E no fragmento que controla o mapa

```
public class MarkersFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setUpMapIfNeeded(); 
    }
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() { 
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (markersMapFragment == null) {
            markersMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.markersMapFragment));
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (markersMapFragment != null) {
                markersMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mGoogleMap) {
                        if (mGoogleMap != null) {
                            ...
                            ...
                            LatLng tLatLng, mLatLng;
                            mLatLng = new LatLng(-23.5492, -46.6336);
                            // iterates through the runList as instance of RunData
                            for (RunData runData : runList) { 
                                tLatLng = addMarkers(runData.collect_lat, runData.collect_lng, runData.collect_address, runData.collect_person, runData.delivery_lat, runData.delivery_lng, runData.delivery_address, runData.delivery_person, runData.run_parcel, mGoogleMap);
                                ...
                                ...                               
                            }
                            // Show the current location in Google Map
                            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatLng));
                            // Zoom in the Google Map
                            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));
                            ...
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    // metodo que adiciona os marcadores.
    public LatLng addMarkers(String collectLat, String collectLng, String collectAddress, String collectPerson,
                             String deliveryLat, String deliveryLng, String deliveryAddress, String deliveryPerson,
                             String parcel, GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng cLatLng, dLatLng;
        String mSnippet;
        // add collect marker
        if ((collectLat != null & collectLng != null) && (collectLat.length() > 0 & collectLng.length() > 0)) {
            ...
            ...
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(cLatLng)
                    .icon(collectMarker)
                    .title(collectAddress)
                    .draggable(false)
                    .snippet(mSnippet)
            );
        } 

        // add delivery marker
        if ((deliveryLat != null & deliveryLng != null) && (deliveryLat.length() > 0 & deliveryLng.length() > 0)) {
            ...
            ...
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(dLatLng)
                    .icon(deliveryMarker)
                    .title(deliveryAddress)
                    .draggable(false)
                    .snippet(mSnippet)
            );
        }
        // retorna LatLng ou null
        if (cLatLng != null) {
            return cLatLng;
        } else if (dLatLng != null) {
            return dLatLng;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // metodo que adiciona os marcadores de coleta e entrega de um unico registro
    // executado pela atividade controladora
    public void addSingleMarker(RunData runData) {
        final String collectLat = runData.collect_lat;
        final String collectLng = runData.collect_lng;
        ...
        ...

        if (markersMapFragment == null) {
            markersMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.markersMapFragment));
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (markersMapFragment != null) {
                markersMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mGoogleMap) {
                        LatLng mLatLng;
                        mLatLng = new LatLng(-23.5492, -46.6336);
                        if (mGoogleMap != null) {
                            mLatLng = addMarkers(collectLat, collectLng, collectAddress, collectPerson, deliveryLat, deliveryLng, deliveryAddress, deliveryPerson, parcel, mGoogleMap);
                            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatLng));
                            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            if (markersMapFragment != null) {
                markersMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mGoogleMap) {
                        LatLng mLatLng;
                        mLatLng = new LatLng(-23.5492, -46.6336);
                        if (mGoogleMap != null) {
                            mLatLng = addMarkers(collectLat, collectLng, collectAddress, collectPerson, deliveryLat, deliveryLng, deliveryAddress, deliveryPerson, parcel, mGoogleMap);
                            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatLng));
                            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Destaco novamente a linha

```
MarkersFragment mFragment = (MarkersFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.viewpager);
```

Ela funciona na vertical porque a view R.id.viewpager é instanciada, e como eu disse as outras views retornam null

Diante do codigo exposto, você poderia me orientar a como referenciar a view mais adequada?

(Se achar que tem código demasiado, fique a vontade para eliminar qualquer excesso).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma de resolver isso depende de como tem estruturado o seu código.

Uma das abordagens usadas é a Activity gerir os dois Fragments, fazendo de intermediário entre eles.

Assim, quando um Fragment quer que uma acção seja executada em outro Fragment, o primeiro pede à Activity que informe o segundo dessa intenção.

Neste caso o Fragment do Dialog chama um método da Activity, passando as informações necessárias, para que ele chame um método do Fragment do mapa para adicionar o Marker.

Veja em [Como passar o valor do EditText de um Fragment para o TextView de outro Fragment?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58407/2541) e [Alterar componentes do Fragment através de uma Activity](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149982/2541) como foram resolvidas situações semelhantes  esta.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando o mínimo de detalhes fornecidos na sua pergunta, vou tentar abaixo mostrar como seria o básico se tratando de [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/?hl=pt-br). Veja abaixo uma simples classe no qual é marcada com um ponto definindo latitude e latitude utilizando [**Marcadores**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker):

```
public class MapPane extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(41.889, -87.622), 16));

        // You can customize the marker image using images bundled with
        // your app, or dynamically generated bitmaps.
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.house_flag))
                .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left
                .position(new LatLng(41.889, -87.622)));
    }
}
```

> Como eu faço pra inserir os marcadores no mapa ao inserir uma nova
>   tarefa?

No momento em que você inserir essa nova tarefa, bastar você inserir um novo marcador desta forma:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.
fromResource(R.drawable.house_flag))
                    .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) 
                    .position(new LatLng(41.889, -87.622)));
```

Segue abaixo uma **adicional** no qual pode fazer um teste clicando em qualquer ponto do mapa para adicionar um marcador de acordo com a coordenada. Veja:

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                            new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).title("New Marker");

                    googleMap.addMarker(marker);

                System.out.println(point.latitude+"---"+ point.longitude);  
                }
            });
```

Para mais detalhes, é só você seguir as orientações da [**documentação**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/?hl=pt-br) no website do Android.

Comment: Espero que, com os novos detalhes, veja que a resposta correta que deu, não tem relação com a questão central.

Comment: @ReneFreak Os marcadores estão sendo adicionado através do sqlite?

Comment: Não. O banco de dados só tem uma tabela com os dados que vc ve no card, mais as coordenadas. Ou seja, guardo os endereços e a lat. e long. tanto da coleta como da entrega.

Comment: No evento `onMapReady` recupero a tabela e interajo com cada registro,  usando as lat/lng para adicionar o marcador.

Caso não tenha lat./long. Uso o endereço pra tentar acha-las.

Answer (score 1):

Acabei achando uma solução para 'achar' o elemento correto no fragment do mapa e inserir os markers. O método de interface:

```
public void addMarkersToMap(RunData runData) {
    if (runData != null) {
        MarkersFragment mFragment = (MarkersFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.viewpager);

        mFragment.addSingleMarker(runData); 
}
```

ficou assim:

```
public void addMarkersToMap(RunData runData) {
    if (runData != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        MarkersFragment mFragment;

        if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            mFragment = (MarkersFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.markersMapPanel);
        } else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            mFragment = (MarkersFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.viewpager);
        }

        if (mFragment != null) {
            mFragment.addSingleMarker(runData);
        }

    }
}
```