# Como lidar com location services em fragmentos

Tags: android, android-fragment, google-location-api

Estou criando um app (Android) com dois fragmentos, um com uma lista de endereços e outro com um mapa apontando para estes endereços. Na vertical, estão em tab deslizantes e na horizontal, ficam lado a lado, ou seja, ambos estão sempre ativos.

E ambos precisam acessar a localização. Só no inicio, mas logo no inicio.

O mapa usa para abrir centralizado na posição do aparelho.

Na listagem serve de centro geográfico para limitar as sugestões de endereços.

Eu já consigo a localização no painel do mapa. Usei esta [lib](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib) que funciona muito bem e é bem simples de usar, ou seja, não preciso de guia pra achar a localização.

Só que antes de repetir a formula no outro fragmento, eu queria saber se existe um jeito melhor de fazer isso.

Por exemplo, se eu soubesse como pegar a localização na activity e passar para os fragmentos, assim não precisaria repetir.

Ou talvez exista outra maneira. Você pode me mostrar?

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/176203/2541)

Comment: Fui eu mesmo que fiz aquela pergunta. Entendi como passar as informações de um fragmento para outro e de e para a mainActivity. Ao menos, quando o processamento é direto (sincrono). Mas não no caso de call backs. E é este o caso. Por que o método FusedLocation retorna a localização de forma assincrona. Poderia me dar alguma dica neste sentido ou apontar algum artigo/resposta?

Comment: Não tendo mais informação, em principio, basta chamar o método do fragmento no método(callback) da Activity que recebe a localização.

Comment: Rene, ficou esclarecido?

Comment: Acho que entendi sim. Mas deixa eu fazer pra confirmar.

Comment: Estou cá a pensar em como fazer isso. Imagino que tenha de fazer um par de métodos em cada fragmento que seriam getter e setter de um campo LatLng (representando a localização). Assim, na mainActivity eu obtenho a localização e chamo os metodos setters dos fragmentos. Dai, dentro dos fragmentos, usaria os getters pra obter a localização dentro deles. Tá certo este raciocinio?

Comment: Talvez não seja necessários os getter. Como o resultado é assíncrono, o setter, além de atribuir o valor ao campo, poderá ter de actualizar algo mais, eventualmente alguma view(não sei o que o fragment faz).

Comment: Em um dos fragmentos, a localização serve para centrar um `googlemap`. No outro, serve de centro para um campo `LatLngBounds` que por sua vez é usado para delimitar sugestões em um `AutoCompleteTextView` De qualquer forma, estou usando suas dicas para evoluir o `app`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi criar uma classe estendendo `Application` de forma a usar como um `singleton`.

```
public class Here extends Application {

 private static Here sInstance;
 public LatLng myLocation;

 public static Here getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;
 }

 @Override
 public void onTerminate() {
    // Do your application wise Termination task
    super.onTerminate();
 }

 public LatLng getMyLocation() {
    return myLocation;
 }

 public void setMyLocation(LatLng latLng) {
    myLocation = latLng;
 }
}
```

Quando o `listener` de localização recebe uma atualização usa `Here.setMyLocation()` para guarda-la e ela fica disponível para o aplicativo como um todo.