# Como de um Fragment chamar método de outro fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Olá, como eu consigo chamar um método que está em um outro fragment através do `android:onclick =""`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58454/2541), [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97389/2541) e [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149984/2541)

Comment: Um fragment não deve manipular outro fragment, apenas Activity deve fazer isso, as respostas acima resolvem o problema.